# How to search for a part of a word and replace the whole word afterwards?

Tags: ms-word

I have a relatively big Word document containing Tweets. I now want to replace all links in that file. Every link starts with http, is there a possibility to find all words that start with http but then delete the whole word/link?

I have tried using the search and replace option but I couldn't find a solution.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This would seem off-topic for the stack overflow forum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic More appropriate would be posting in https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word - or - http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/ - or - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1473637240674

Answer (score 0):

You could use python to process the entire file,
I would advise creating a second file where you storage the result.
A little code that should do what you want.

```
with open("filename", 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

words = content.split(" ")

filtered_word = [word for word in words if not word.startswith("http")]

content = " ".join(filtered_word)

with open("filename_result", 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: I first used the iOS Version of Word but there I couldn't use wildcards. Now I used a Windows version of Word and through the search and replace option I used "http*" to search for all links.